# Set State in Functional Component from React Table ColumnDef

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Hey just got my hands on typescript and react and started to make a project where i use react-table.

Now im faceing the problem that i dont know how to update a state (useState) of my main functional component  from the ColumnDef.

So basicly i want to open a delete dialog by using a button defined in the ColumnDef of react-table.

ColumnDef:

```
export const columns: ColumnDef<Component>[] = [
{
    id: "actions",
    enableHiding: false,
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      const component = row.original;
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      return (
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
              <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
              <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(component.articleNumber);
                toast({
                  title: "✅ Copied Article Number",
                });
              }}
            >
              Copy Article Number
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => {
                // **OPEN THE DELETE DIALOG**
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => navigate("/documents/" + component._id)}
            >
              Show Documents
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      );
    },
  },
];
```

Dialog:

```
interface DeleteAlertDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  id: string;
  handleOpen: (value: boolean) => void;
}

function DeleteAlertDialog({ open, id, handleOpen }: DeleteAlertDialogProps) {
  return (
    <AlertDialog open={open}>
      <AlertDialogContent>
        <AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
          <AlertDialogDescription>{id}</AlertDialogDescription>
        </AlertDialogHeader>
        <AlertDialogFooter>
          <AlertDialogCancel onClick={() => handleOpen(false)}>
            Cancel
          </AlertDialogCancel>
          <AlertDialogAction>Continue</AlertDialogAction>
        </AlertDialogFooter>
      </AlertDialogContent>
    </AlertDialog>
  );
}
```

Main Component:

```
export function ComponentsDataTable() {
  const [deleteComponentOpen, setDeleteComponentOpen] = React.useState(false);
 
  const accessToken = "FAKE";

  const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/components";
  const fetcher = (url: string) => fetchData(url, accessToken);
  const { data, mutate } = useSWR(url, fetcher, {
    suspense: true,
  });

  function handleMutate() {
    mutate();
  }

  const [sorting, setSorting] = React.useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = React.useState<ColumnFiltersState>(
    []
  );
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] =
    React.useState<VisibilityState>({});
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = React.useState({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  });

  **I SOMEHOW NEED TO PASS THIS FUNCTION TO THE COLUMNDEF ????**
  function handleDeleteComponentOpen(value: boolean) {
    setDeleteComponentOpen(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex items-center space-x-4 py-4">
        <Input
          placeholder="Filter Tagname..."
          value={(table.getColumn("tagname")?.getFilterValue() as string) ?? ""}
          onChange={(event) =>
            table.getColumn("tagname")?.setFilterValue(event.target.value)
          }
          className="max-w-sm"
        />
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" className="ml-auto">
              Columns <ChevronDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            {table
              .getAllColumns()
              .filter((column) => column.getCanHide())
              .map((column) => {
                return (
                  <DropdownMenuCheckboxItem
                    key={column.id}
                    className="capitalize"
                    checked={column.getIsVisible()}
                    onCheckedChange={(value) =>
                      column.toggleVisibility(!!value)
                    }
                  >
                    {column.id}
                  </DropdownMenuCheckboxItem>
                );
              })}
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
        <CreateDialog mutateDataParent={handleMutate} />
      </div>
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end space-x-2 py-4">
        <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
          {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
        </div>
        <div className="space-x-2">
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <DeleteAlertDialog
        open={deleteComponentOpen}
        id={"test"}
        handleOpen={handleDeleteComponentOpen}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I not able to find any good information about this.
Would be great if someone can help or provide a link.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should update the columns variable to a function where you can pass a state update function as a param

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Thank you for the inspiration. I was totally stuck and in the end the solution was so simple

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has the same problem. Just use a function and return the column defintion. Then pass a function to handle stuff.

```
interface ColumnDefinitionHandlerProps {
  handleDeleteComponent: (open: boolean, id: string) => void;
}

export function ColumnDefinitionHandler({
    handleDeleteComponent,
}: ColumnDefinitionHandlerProps): ColumnDef<Component>[] {
    const columns: ColumnDef<Component>[] = [{/*Definitions*/}]
    return columns
}

// Blow Code is inside Main Component
const columns = ColumnDefinitionHandler({ handleDeleteComponent });

const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns: columns,
    //...
})
```

Comment: This is correct---being able to define columns independently like this is one of `react-table`'s super powers.  And keep the data fully typed.